# javascript array enumerator

Tags: javascript, c#, ienumerator

I'm thinking of rolling my own solution to see if I can extend an observable array with something like moveNext, Reset, Current, and all the other functionality that you can use with an IEnumerator in C#. The problem is that I can't get a reference to primitives in javascript arrays. So I'm having to base it on the current index. I am however running into a problem of if the array is changed then I can't tell which element of the array the enumerator is supposed to be on.

for example here's an array

[1,3,3,3,3,5]

lets say that current is at the index of [2]

if the index of [3] or [4] is removed, then current would be unaffected, but it would also be indistinguishable from removing [1] or [2]. Because I can't record a reference i have to go by index, but if the number of elements in the array changes, then the enumerator has no way to tell if the remove was on something before or after the current. This is even with recording the last version of the array. Any idea's of how to go about this so that current can remain accurate? and if current happens to be the element removed, to make current point to the next element?

Comment: You should not be changing the array while enumerating it; as far as I remember in C# such thing even cause a runtime error.

Comment: Make it an object and set the original position as an attribute

Comment: You could create your own array-like class, have it wrap the actual array but have all the operations which can modify the array do the right thing with regard to the 'current' internal pointer. At that point, though, you should take a step back and ask 'why?', 'what do I really gain?' and 'are those gains worth the overhead?' (dev time, headaches, maintenance etc.)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, Right you are, thanks

Comment: Cheers! You still need help on this?

Comment: No, I'm just going to set a flag that will throw an exception if the array has been changed, and changed back if the enumerate get's reset.

Comment: @PatrickM Perhaps it's not worth it, but I was hoping somebody might have already done it. For a language as asynchronous capable as javascript, it seems to me that an enumerator would be of great value. I'd like to do something outside of a loop that still is capable of iteration over an array. Also, I'm trying to extend it with knockouts observableArray. Anyway, I'll just make it so that if it's changed the enumerator is no longer valid